# Hyperlink inside QGIS 'Maptips'

Tags: qgis, html, maptips

I have [BGS 50k vector data](https://www.bgs.ac.uk/services/NGDC/citedData/catalogue/88d90a50-3e48-4501-8760-883af95f060f.html) which includes a field referring to the [LEX code](http://data.bgs.ac.uk/doc/Lexicon.html) on the BGS website. Obviously the web address will be unique for every geological formation so I need to insert the field into the map tips window.

I have laid out the information in table format which is why I have `<tr>` and `<td>` tags. I have tried typing the following with no success.

```
<tr><td class="bold">BGS Link:</td><td><a href="[% "LEX_WEB" %]"></a></td></tr>
```

or

```
<tr><td class="bold">BGS Link:</td><td><a href=[% "LEX_WEB" %]></a></td></tr>
```

and

```
<tr><td class="bold">BGS Link:</td><a href=<td>"[% "LEX_WEB" %]"></td></a></tr>
```

or

```
<tr><td class="bold">BGS Link:</td><a href=<td>[% "LEX_WEB" %]></td></a></tr>
```

The last two produce the hyperlink at the very top of the map tip but when clicking it, my web browser does not follow it. Strange thing, I can't even reproduce the hyperlink outside the table format!

If you are keen to test it out I have left the my table styling below. I propose setting up a shapefile with a 'Link' field and entering something like 'www.google.com'.

```
<style> 
body { 
background-color: white!important; 
font-family: sans-serif; 
width: 200px; 
} 

table { 
border-collapse: collapse; 
} 

th { 
font-size: 15px; 
text-transform: uppercase; 
padding: 10px; 
background: #006c1c; 
color: white; 
} 

tr { 
border: 2px solid white; 
} 

tr:nth-child (odd) { 
background:grey!important; 
} 

td { 
font-size: 12px; 
white-space: nowrap; 
padding: 5px; 
background:#eaeaea; 
} 

td.h2{ 
font-size: 15px; 
float: left!important; 
font-weight: bold; 
background:grey; 
color:white; 
} 

td.bold { 
font-size: 12px; 
font-weight: bold; 
} 
td.gap { 
background-color:white; 
padding:1px; 
} 
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of your attempts at HTML are actually going to create a link.

Try something like:

```
 <a href="http://google.com?q=[% "STATE_NAME" %]">[% "STATE_NAME" %]</a>
```

Where you add the field to the URL **AND** provide some text to link to, in this case the state name field but it could be a simple text string like `link`.